# View elements not showing when mixing programmatic and IB design

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

forgive me if I am positing in the wrong place, I am new to the forum and to *Swift/Xcode*

I am trying to mix programmatic code and IB elements.

This all works fine and I can add buttons etc to it as needed.

BUT I am trying to do some programmatically and adding for example a button using the IB

But the IB button does not show,

I am obviously doing something silly / not doing something // or just lack a fundamental grapsp of the View hierarchy

Can you advise please

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fff = ff(frame: self.view.frame)

        self.view.addSubview(fff)

        // Have also tried self.view = fff
    }

}
```

Comment: What does method `ff` do?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `@IBDesignable` with anything that does not inherit from `UIView`. So, in this case, it is invalid to use it with a UIViewController and does not actually do anything. A more appropriate use of `@IBDesignable` is when you have a custom `UIView` subclass that you want to show in the interface builder. That would render properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response and noted about the IBDesignable. I think the question I am asking badly is really this. How do I set thet UIView I am programmatically editing and adding elements such as buttons to, to be the one I can also edit in IB. So that I can have the same view with programatic elements AND IB added elements. I thought that by creating a custom UIView and then setting it to self.view = fff (fff being my custom UIView) would enable me to do this.

Comment: But it doesn't - it just places my programmatically created view over the top of my IB view so that I cannot see the IB elements unless it is set to opaque.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the interface builder. All you need to do is go to the interface builder (storyboard) and drag an element on to the screen. After you do that, you can hold 'control' and drag that element into your code file and it will make a reference. This documentation might help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1

Comment: Thanks Cole, I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. I am happy with using the IB it’s just I am trying to do both, use the IB and programmatically add elements on the same UIView